# Get VariableSizedWrapGrid to virtualise

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a gridview. But since i am dumping a lot of data into it, it's throwing an overload exception.

I can solve this on a normal gridview by setting a width and height, it will then virtualise the data.

The difference here is i have also set the items panel. This is preventing the virutalisation to kick in.

I can get it working again by setting a width on the VariableSizedWrapGrid but this is not showing a scrollbar, making it pretty useless.

```
    <GridView x:Name="ItemGridView" Width="500" Height="400" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" Margin="6" Grid.Row="1">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Width="450" Height="350" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Any ideas how i can get this combination working?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could put your GridView in the ScrollViewer element like:

```
 <ScrollViewer>
  <Grid>
   <GridView x:Name="ItemGridView" Width="500" Height="400" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" Margin="6" Grid.Row="1">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Width="450" Height="350" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView >
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: The scrollviewer wouldn't show due to the fixed height/width of the gridview.

Comment: What about setting the GridView with auto in Width and Height?